# Javascript question

Tags: javascript

What do you usually do with Javascript? I use it to validate form, creating drop down menu and was wondering if you guys use it for other purposes. After all, Jquery is better from my point of view......

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: Do you mean to ask what we do with non-jQuery JavaScript?

Comment: Jquery is a library of JavaScript functions. That's like saying that a book written in English is better than English.

Comment: I understand jquery is javascript. However, I am looking for a web developer job and people is always not happy about I am using Jquery instead of javascript.....

Comment: I had problems with using jQuery in Firefox extensions so I have to use plain JS there.

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused, jQuery is written in JavaScript.

Anyway, I use both for all sorts of functions on the front-end, including:

- Creating nice grids of data using jqGrid
- Creating themed dialog boxes, buttons, spinners, etc using jQuery UI
- Easily setting / retrieving values from the DOM using jQuery selectors and `val`, `text`, `html`, etc...
- Easily querying web services using jQuery AJAX

I could really just keep going on and on :)

But very little of this uses raw JavaScript. About all I use raw JavaScript for are those things that are not necessary for jQuery to provide, which usually boils down to:

- String and Array functions
- Integer / String conversions functions

Comment: +1 for a fine constructive answer to sort out the OP's misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

I use javascript for improving the UI of a web page. For example, I use it to cache data locally which would otherwise require multiple calls to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just a framework, written in JavaScript, to simplify and enhance the functionality of JavaScript.

What do you usually do with JavaScript?  Whatever you need to do... I am getting more in-depth with jQuery and using it for building entire interfaces and controlling every little action.